# How to display progress bar of video progress?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, directshow, delphi-5, dspack

I am using Delphi 5.

I am able to display the .avi or any other video clips using `TFilterGraph`, but i need to display the progress of video completion, so how could I do that using `TFilterGraph`.

I need to run next video immediately, so how could I do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should request IMediaSeeking interface from the graph object and then call its GetPositions method to learn current position in playback.

Also you can request IMediaEvent interface from the same graph object and then in your main loop get graph events. You'll get EC_COMPLETE event the moment playback ends.